# Upgrade jquery from 1.4 to 1.9 above

Tags: jquery, upgrade

Can somebody please show me light to upgrade jquery from 1.4 to 1.9 or above?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I think you need to start with the change logs/upgrade notes that comes with each jQuery release - the most important one could be the [1.9 upgrade guid](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Comment: visit http://jquery.com

Comment: Are you looking for instructions on replacing a local file, changing the url to a CDN, or how to update the code you've written that works with 1.4 so that it works with 1.9?

Comment: @JasonAller: I have a site that has jquery scripts written in 1.4 so I am to make them compatible with latest jqeury or atleast 1.9.

Comment: The video "jQuery Migrate Plugin Tutorial - Upgrade to v3.0" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqDE2el_epw will give you the steps to complete the upgrade you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this, it shows a list of to check for in your javascript code: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/